# Is it possible to autoforward bitcoins to another address?

Tags: development

we would like to accept BTC for our token sale. In order to achieve that, we need a specific BTC address for every contributor.

The contribution flow is:
- investor sends BTC to their dedicated address
- the contribution is recorded in an offchain database
- the BTC is forwarded to a central account

as I don't know if this is even possible, some pointers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need to forward the coins to a different address? You already control the private keys for the address that they were sent to, no need to move them to another address in your wallet. All you are doing is incurring additional transaction fees.

Instead of forwarding them to another address, just make sure that you have the private keys to all of the coins and spend them from those addresses as necessary.

If you are doing this for auditing purposes, then use an HD wallet and publish the master public key. This allows anyone to derive the addresses that you used (without needing the private keys or having access to them) to check the balance of your wallet. If you do that, just make sure that you do not reveal any of the child private keys as that will result in the master private key (and thus all of your child private keys) being revealed.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I come from Ethereum development where I created a smart-contract for that functionality. But having multiple addresses linked to a wallet should do the trick too